# Cannot get C++ std::shared_timed_mutex.try_lock_for() to compile

Tags: c++, mutex

using VS2017

I am trying to get use std::shared_timed_mutex and specifically  the member function try_lock_for.
I am trying to specify 100ms for the timeout.

Now edited with Alan Birtles help.
I now have

```
#include <chrono>                   // for std::chrono
#include <shared_mutex>             // for std::shared_timed_mutex
#include <iostream>                 // for std::cerr

static std::shared_timed_mutex   SHMutex;

void testfunc()
{
          using duration2 = std::chrono::duration<_int64, std::milli>;
          // WAS using duration2 = std::chrono::duration<_int64, std::chrono::milliseconds>;
        const duration2 dur(100);
        if (!SHMutex.try_lock_for(dur))
            std::cerr << "Lock failure for SHMutex" << '\n';
}
```

No matter what I do, Visual Studio complains with compilation errors on the instantiation errors of dur. What do I have to do, to get this working?

Compilation errors are now zero. Alan Birtles answer made the difference

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the compilation error(s) as text verbatim.

Answer (score 5):

```
using duration2 = std::chrono::duration<_int64, std::chrono::milliseconds>;
```

Makes no sense, the second template argument for `duration` is a ratio but `std::chrono::milliseconds` is a duration. Use either:

```
using duration2 = std::chrono::duration<_int64, std::milli>;
```

Or simpler:

```
using duration2 = std::chrono::milliseconds;
```

Which will be something similar on most platforms (the representation for `std::chrono::milliseconds` is defined as `signed integer type of at least 45 bits` see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)